# Xcode - Write and Delete to Plist

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I have a plist with two arrays that looks like this:

[image]

I currently load the plist like this:

```
// Find path of plist
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameofPList" ofType:@"plist"];


// Read the data into arrays
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *tableData = [dict objectForKey:@"array2"];
```

1. How do I write new items to the "array2" array in the plist (code, not manually)
2. How do I delete items from "array2"? (code, not manually)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
NSMutableArray *tableData = [dict[@"array2"] mutableCopy];
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(otherwise you'll get an immutable array).

Add items with:

```
[tableData addObject:@"new item"];
```

Delete with:

```
[tableData removeObjectAtIndex:someIndex];
```

or:

```
[tableData removeObject:someObject];
```

and anything else you can find in the [`NSMutableArray` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/).

**However** "write back" sounds like you are attempting to write the `.plist` back into the app bundle.  While this will work in the iOS Simulator, it will fail on a real devices.

You cannot write to the app bundle at runtime; write to the *Documents* folder instead and be flexible about where to read from.

Comment: May I know would this edit be reflected in plist as well. I were trying the same bt any change in array through code does not gets reflected in plist as well...

Comment: Yes, it will when you do `[tableData writeToFile:atomically:]`.

Comment: Yeah, within the *Documents* folder (search for how to get that).